# I/flutter ( 7573): Error ::FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) I/flutter ( 7573): <br /> I/flutter ( 7573): ^

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart

i keep getting this error when i want to sign in into the app while doing my flutter app.Can you guys help me?

In addition i am using dart language and also mysql database.

Also i noticed that when i type the fetch_assoc() in my login php. There is no option of fetch_assoc() shown, so i wonder if that's the cause of the error?

Please i need your help on this matter. Thankyou very much.

This is my login.php code:

```
<?php

include '../connection.php';



$userEmail = $_POST['EmailUser'];

$userPassword = md5($_POST['PasswordUser']);



$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE EmailUser = '$userEmail' AND PasswordUser = '$userPassword'"                                                                          ;



$resultOfQuery = $connectNow->query($sqlQuery);



if($resultOfQuery->num_rows > 0)//allow user to login (record found)

{

    $userRecord = array(); 

    while($rowFound = $resultOfQuery->fetch_assoc()) 

    {

        $userRecord[] = $rowFound;

    }



    echo json_decode( 

        array( 

            "success" =>true,

            "userData" =>$userRecord[0],

            )

    );

}

else// not allow if wrong either one

{

    echo json_encode(array("success"=>false));

}
```

This is my service:

```
loginUserNow() async {
    try {
      var res = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(API.login),
        body: {
          "EmailUser": emailcontroller.text.trim(),
          "PasswordUser": passwordcontroller.text.trim(),
        },
      );

      if (res.statusCode == 200) //from flutter app to server connection suc
      {
        var resBodyOfLogin = jsonDecode(res.body);
        if (resBodyOfLogin['success'] == true) {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: " you are Logged in Successfully.");

          User userInfo = User.fromJson(resBodyOfLogin["userData"]);
          //save user info to local storage usin the Shared Preference

          await RememberUserPrefs.saveRememberUser(userInfo);

          //send user to dashboard or default screen
          // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
          Get.to(DashboardOfFragments());
        } else {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "Incorrect Credentials. Please try again.");
        }
      }
    } catch (errorMsg) {
      // ignore: avoid_print, prefer_interpolation_to_compose_strings
      print("Error ::" + errorMsg.toString());
    }
  }
```

This is my user preferences:

```
import 'dart:convert';



import 'package:kezooapp/users/model/user.dart';

import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';



class RememberUserPrefs {

  //save-remember User-info

  static Future<void> saveRememberUser(User userInfo) async {

    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    String userJsonData = jsonEncode(userInfo.toJson());



    await preferences.setString("currentUser", userJsonData);

  }

}
```

This is my model:

```
class User {

  int IdUser;

  String NameUser;

  String EmailUser;

  String PasswordUser;



  User(

    this.IdUser,

    this.NameUser,

    this.EmailUser,

    this.PasswordUser,

  );



  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(

        int.parse(json["IdUser"]),

        json["NameUser"],

        json["EmailUser"],

        json["PasswordUser"],

      );



  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {

        'IdUser': IdUser.toString(),

        'NameUser': NameUser,

        'EmailUser': EmailUser,

        'PasswordUser': PasswordUser,

      };

}
```

This is my error i keep getting:

```
I/flutter ( 7573): Error ::FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

I/flutter ( 7573): <br />

I/flutter ( 7573): ^
```

Comment: Note MD5 for passwords is insecure, [ref](https://code-boxx.com/password-encrypt-decrypt-php/), and use prepared statements. Also advisable avoid `select *` and return only needed data (mainly for efficiency, but a small amount of exposure too of password storage).

Comment: Stop your Dart code with a breakpoint before `jsonDecode(res.body)` and inspect the value of `res.body`. It is almost sure an HTML formatted PHP error message or warning, which will help you to understand what is your issue. And listen to @danblack, your current PHP code does not prevent SQL injection.